# Sort a Table so that 1 value(State) is always last while still sorting by a second value (time)

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a table that I want to organize by the amount of time remaining. But I also want to have it sorted so that any line with a value of "Broke" appears at the end. Here is the code that I currently have.

```
Sub SortByTimeRemaining()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").ListObjects("FullSNList__FBD").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("FullSNList__FBD[Service Tag]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
            CustomOrder:="Broke", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("FullSNList__FBD[TimeValue]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Apply
    End With
    Columns("M:AT").ColumnWidth = 8
End Sub
```

The picture below is some example data. It is partially working but the issue is that it is sorting each different Service Tag Value by their time value. I want to have it so that only Broke is at the bottom while the rest are just organized by their Time value.

Not sure if this is possible but I would appreciate any advice!

UPDATE: With the suggestions of 2 people in the comments, I have added a helper cell and it works great! Accepting answer!

[image: Sorting Table]

Comment: That is not possible. If your first sort criteria is the service tag and your second is time it will sort first by service tag and each service tag by time then. Sort does not support what you ask for.

Comment: Just add a new column that is True/False something like ```=[@[Service Tag]="Broke"``` and then use that to sort as the first criteria instead of the ServiceTag column

Comment: Well, if you sort so broke is at the bottom, then change the range to exclude those "Broke" rows then you can sort on other criteria, but it will be a two-step process...

Comment: @SolarMike guess this is a bit cumbersome with list objects aka tables.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ agreed, but it was just an idea as I did that manually once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible.
If your first sort criteria is the service tag and your second is time it will sort first by service tag and each service tag by time then. Sort does not support what you ask for.

As workaround add a helper column with the formula

```
=[@[Service Tag]]="Broke"
```

and then sort by helper column and time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you insert a secondary column as "Num" (e.g), set others as 1, and Broken as 2,
then run filter with 3 fields, it will show what you exactly need.